# Unresolved reference: FontAwesomeIconView - What library should I import?

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

Following a Tornadofx tutorial, I am trying to use a function called FontAwesomeIconView() that is to be used to define a Fieldset. The problem is that I don't know what library to import in order to use FontAwesomeIconView.

The tutorial I'm using is here: https://github.com/edvin/tornadofx/wiki/. I tried searching for information about FontAwesomeIconView but came up dry.

The code used for this example is as follows:

```
class CustomerForm : View() {
    override val root = Form()

    val customer = Customer()

    init {
        title = "Register Customer"

        with (root) {
            fieldset("Personal Information", FontAwesomeIconView(USER)) {
                field("Name") {
                    textfield().bind(customer.nameProperty())
                }

            }
        }
    }

}
```

I expected to see "Personal Information" text displayed in a larger, bold font with a User icon. But I'm just getting an error saying FontAwesomeIconView is an unresolved reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the dependency `de.jensd.fontawesomefx` to your project :) In the TornadoFX distribution we use it for testing, like this (Maven Syntax, adjust to your build system):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.jensd</groupId>
    <artifactId>fontawesomefx</artifactId>
    <version>8.9</version>
</dependency>
```